# Do any modern airliners have a non-flat floor in the passenger cabin?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, cabin-design

Are there any non-flat (sloped or stepped) passenger cabins in modern commercial planes? E.g. the floor at the back of the cabin is a few centimeters higher than at the front?

Comment: @min: no, I mean floor of the cabin not flat, but e.g. going "up" in the tail. Recently I was in last rows (off from normal chairs) in an Airbus, and I had the impression that the last part of the cabin went up. Probably in my case was because of cabin form, but so I had such question:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some Airbus aircraft have this characteristic, in the rear section of the cabin floor. You can see this in the following image. The rear passenger windows slope up following the floor slope.

[image: A340]

A340 line drawings; image from [wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Line_drawings_of_Airbus_aircraft)

This image of the upper cargo deck of A330 MRTT upper cargo deck (which would be the cabin floor in the passenger version) shows the upward slope.

[image: A330MRTT]

A330MRTT cabin floor; image from [thinkdefence.co.uk](http://www.thinkdefence.co.uk/2011/07/the-pros-and-7-cons-of-an-raf-voyager/)

Apparently, this is a common trait in A300/310/340/330's to allow more containerized cargo in the rear.

Comment: What I get from the drawings: A340-600 is *really* long!

Answer (score 4):

The new [honda jet](http://www.flyingmag.com/we-fly-honda-aircraft-ha-420#page-2) has a stepped cabin floor but it is center/out not front/back. Note the recessed channel in the middle.

[image] 
([source](http://static1.businessinsider.com/image/5384a69b6bb3f7d439dfdb96-1200-800/hondajet_interior_1.jpg))

The [Beech King Air](http://beechcraft.txtav.com/en/king-air-350i) (a fairly common charter plane) also has a single step as you move forward in the cabin

[image] 
([source](http://beechcraft.txtav.com/en/king-air-350i))

Comment: I wouldn't call either of these "airliners"

Comment: I admit the term `airliner` is a little ambiguous, but "this ain't it". Also, that King Air "step" is hardly a step. It is a bump about 6" wide that covers the wing spar carry through. Your picture just makes it look like a step up. The King Air *does* have the recessed channel in the center isle, however.

Comment: Oh, the monochrome! That HondaJet interior hurts my eyes!

Comment: @FreeMan I blame the lighting.

Comment: They must have just discovered beige.